# How to set up the highest possible uniform distribution of observations by cluster in R

Tags: r

```
mydata=structure(list(v1 = c(1895L, 1776L, 1732L, 1709L, 1563L, 1513L, 
1498L, 1442L, 1426L, 1391L, 1346L, 1319L, 1311L, 1303L, 1299L, 
1287L, 1287L, 1284L, 1276L, 1273L, 1256L, 1224L, 1206L, 1206L, 
1186L, 1174L, 1173L, 1166L, 1164L, 1159L, 1154L, 1151L, 1142L, 
1139L, 1133L, 1088L, 1073L, 1068L, NA, NA, NA, NA), v2 = c(6.14, 
8.94, 11.41, 0.14, 2.68, 4.73, 1.61, 1.43, 0, 2.55, 0.65, 0.67, 
5.47, 2.12, 0.44, 2.72, 3.14, 3.85, 0.89, 0.51, 3.65, 2.19, 3.7, 
0.41, 12.09, 1.97, 1.48, 23.5, 0.55, 0.06, 0.61, 1, 3.96, 0.54, 
0.4, 0.37, 0.47, 4.42, 1.37, 2.04, 0.73, 10.12), v3 = c(0, 0.01, 
0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.01), v4 = c(468L, 409L, 134L, 83L, 228L, 435L, 396L, 220L, 
0L, 351L, 347L, 342L, 320L, 59L, 305L, 350L, 63L, 376L, 365L, 
274L, 310L, 296L, 245L, 323L, 66L, 374L, 273L, 290L, 271L, 49L, 
323L, 1L, 268L, 312L, 275L, 219L, 252L, 372L, 243L, 64L, 225L, 
103L), v5 = c(0.25, 0.23, 0.08, 0.05, 0.15, 0.29, 0.26, 0.15, 
0, 0.25, 0.26, 0.26, 0.24, 0.05, 0.23, 0.27, 0.05, 0.29, 0.29, 
0.22, 0.25, 0.24, 0.2, 0.27, 0.06, 0.32, 0.23, 0.25, 0.23, 0.04, 
0.28, 0, 0.23, 0.27, 0.24, 0.2, 0.23, 0.35, 0.23, 0.06, 0.22, 
0.1), v6 = c(12699L, 10879L, 9635L, 10075L, 8772L, 8996L, 9142L, 
8843L, 7809L, 7977L, 7953L, 8100L, 7719L, 7093L, 8388L, 8394L, 
7347L, 8588L, 8687L, 7653L, 7876L, 7536L, 7155L, 7286L, 6569L, 
8011L, 7356L, 7318L, 7122L, 6564L, 7020L, 6604L, 7203L, 7410L, 
6339L, 6473L, 6296L, 7003L, 6266L, 6873L, 5807L, 6941L), v7 = c(6.7, 
6.13, 5.56, 5.9, 5.61, 5.95, 6.1, 6.13, 5.48, 5.73, 5.91, 6.14, 
5.89, 5.44, 6.46, 6.52, 5.71, 6.69, 6.81, 6.01, 6.27, 6.16, 5.93, 
6.04, 5.54, 6.82, 6.27, 6.28, 6.12, 5.66, 6.08, 5.74, 6.31, 6.51, 
5.59, 5.95, 5.87, 6.56, 6.02, 6.65, 5.7, 6.87), v8 = c(14.44, 
10.2, 18.49, 0.81, 5.22, 13.29, 3.3, 10.11, 0.55, 5.25, 1.24, 
1.39, 7.94, 6.38, 2.93, 3.28, 3.57, 8.76, 1.8, 1.31, 7.39, 16.48, 
6.96, 6.79, 12.56, 2.77, 4.24, 32.02, 0.94, 0.32, 2.83, 2.13, 
5.97, 1.2, 1.34, 1.03, 1.01, 6.6, 3.64, 19.42, 1.81, 15.73), 
    v9 = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
    0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0.02, 
    0, 0.02), v10 = c(955L, 935L, 700L, 443L, 420L, 1408L, 1343L, 
    543L, 352L, 704L, 672L, 702L, 580L, 220L, 595L, 656L, 331L, 
    817L, 759L, 631L, 682L, 563L, 567L, 612L, 395L, 766L, 638L, 
    555L, 524L, 257L, 1223L, 124L, 484L, 677L, 857L, 572L, 541L, 
    658L, 416L, 343L, 939L, 446L), v11 = c(0.5, 0.53, 0.4, 0.26, 
    0.27, 0.93, 0.9, 0.38, 0.25, 0.51, 0.5, 0.53, 0.44, 0.17, 
    0.46, 0.51, 0.26, 0.64, 0.59, 0.5, 0.54, 0.46, 0.47, 0.51, 
    0.33, 0.65, 0.54, 0.48, 0.45, 0.22, 1.06, 0.11, 0.42, 0.59, 
    0.76, 0.53, 0.5, 0.62, 0.4, 0.33, 0.92, 0.44), v12 = c(17005L, 
    14321L, 13788L, 13707L, 11591L, 12256L, 12432L, 12609L, 10775L, 
    10764L, 10679L, 11399L, 10122L, 10070L, 10886L, 11686L, 10082L, 
    11951L, 12028L, 10854L, 10601L, 10441L, 9866L, 9497L, 9485L, 
    11584L, 10629L, 10031L, 9585L, 9043L, 9843L, 9159L, 9863L, 
    10200L, 8945L, 8747L, 8367L, 10071L, 8428L, 9856L, 8006L, 
    10140L), v13 = c(8.97, 8.06, 7.96, 8.02, 7.42, 8.1, 8.3, 
    8.74, 7.56, 7.74, 7.93, 8.64, 7.72, 7.73, 8.38, 9.08, 7.83, 
    9.31, 9.43, 8.53, 8.44, 8.53, 8.18, 7.87, 8, 9.87, 9.06, 
    8.6, 8.23, 7.8, 8.53, 7.96, 8.64, 8.96, 7.89, 8.04, 7.8, 
    9.43, 8.1, 9.54, 7.86, 10.03), v14 = c(16.52, 11.28, 20.87, 
    2.49, 6.05, 14.85, 5.63, 14.79, 1.08, 5.74, 2.06, 2.7, 8.42, 
    11.79, 4.36, 4.87, 8.92, 11.74, 2.49, 2.07, 11.34, 34.46, 
    12.23, 7.3, 24.12, 3.42, 4.93, 35.04, 1.4, 0.7, 3.84, 10.86, 
    7.77, 2.79, 3.08, 1.47, 2.75, 8.06, 5.86, 27.64, 2.4, 17.37
    ), v15 = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.03, 0.01, 
    0.01, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.01, 0.01, 0.03, 0, 0.02), v16 = c(1474L, 1392L, 951L, 830L, 
    624L, 2429L, 2270L, 925L, 704L, 972L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 852L, 
    998L, 596L, 1355L, 1120L, 936L, 1092L, 843L, 930L, 893L, 
    742L, 1127L, 964L, 833L, 770L, 519L, 1992L, 594L, 700L, 1025L, 
    1541L, 855L, 926L, 1061L, 547L, 610L, 1383L, 663L), v17 = c(0.78, 
    0.78, 0.55, 0.49, 0.4, 1.61, 1.52, 0.64, 0.49, 0.7, 0.8, 
    0.94, 0.64, 0.41, 0.66, 0.78, 0.46, 1.06, 0.88, 0.74, 0.87, 
    0.69, 0.77, 0.74, 0.63, 0.96, 0.82, 0.71, 0.66, 0.45, 1.73, 
    0.52, 0.61, 0.9, 1.36, 0.79, 0.86, 0.99, 0.53, 0.59, 1.36, 
    0.66), v18 = c(20175L, 16780L, 16459L, 16173L, 13291L, 14681L, 
    14574L, 14949L, 12904L, 12684L, 12544L, 13797L, 11848L, 12169L, 
    12553L, 13983L, 12066L, 14544L, 14095L, 13041L, 12515L, 12375L, 
    11997L, 10907L, 11693L, 13793L, 12462L, 12066L, 11446L, 11076L, 
    11346L, 11411L, 11712L, 12107L, 10553L, 10224L, 10042L, 12442L, 
    9683L, 11839L, 9122L, 12579L), v19 = c(10.65, 9.45, 9.5, 
    9.46, 8.5, 9.7, 9.73, 10.37, 9.05, 9.12, 9.32, 10.46, 9.04, 
    9.34, 9.66, 10.86, 9.38, 11.33, 11.05, 10.24, 9.96, 10.11, 
    9.95, 9.04, 9.86, 11.75, 10.62, 10.35, 9.83, 9.56, 9.83, 
    9.91, 10.26, 10.63, 9.31, 9.4, 9.36, 11.65, 9.3, 11.46, 8.96, 
    12.44), v20 = c(111.31, 110, 88, 86, 86, 89, 100, 65, 98, 
    78, 75, 79, 79, 65, 68, 68, 63, 71, 77, 79, 74, 130.04, 91, 
    60, 80, 66, 65, 106, 68, 59, 63, 67, 134, 61, 71, 64, 61, 
    140, 58, 98, 55, 91), v21 = c(597L, 554L, 508L, 588L, 441L, 
    422L, 423L, 475L, 420L, 388L, 377L, 415L, 410L, 455L, 370L, 
    475L, 425L, 439L, 453L, 401L, 432L, 368L, 369L, 359L, 366L, 
    442L, 395L, 363L, 355L, 391L, 338L, 374L, 320L, 370L, 336L, 
    334L, 302L, 319L, 338L, 336L, 284L, 313L), v22 = c(337L, 
    294L, 359L, 310L, 253L, 255L, 243L, 272L, 274L, 266L, 246L, 
    255L, 209L, 280L, 206L, 274L, 242L, 279L, 293L, 260L, 262L, 
    232L, 236L, 213L, 271L, 273L, 247L, 210L, 238L, 253L, 214L, 
    228L, 214L, 253L, 194L, 203L, 201L, 217L, 204L, 222L, 156L, 
    208L), v23 = c(286L, 250L, 278L, 232L, 214L, 189L, 190L, 
    213L, 208L, 210L, 193L, 220L, 161L, 212L, 162L, 234L, 179L, 
    211L, 228L, 179L, 192L, 172L, 188L, 143L, 194L, 219L, 207L, 
    181L, 170L, 179L, 158L, 174L, 148L, 197L, 159L, 153L, 149L, 
    184L, 142L, 188L, 128L, 170L), v24 = c(251L, 221L, 238L, 
    214L, 169L, 153L, 149L, 176L, 183L, 163L, 156L, 179L, 145L, 
    176L, 122L, 192L, 164L, 195L, 189L, 156L, 156L, 159L, 167L, 
    126L, 179L, 176L, 165L, 161L, 133L, 168L, 134L, 135L, 154L, 
    159L, 113L, 126L, 121L, 165L, 121L, 142L, 102L, 156L), v25 = c(241L, 
    191L, 213L, 178L, 125L, 136L, 128L, 148L, 151L, 143L, 136L, 
    151L, 137L, 158L, 118L, 165L, 125L, 144L, 169L, 144L, 142L, 
    129L, 132L, 114L, 145L, 154L, 148L, 152L, 120L, 133L, 100L, 
    129L, 122L, 123L, 109L, 106L, 101L, 152L, 102L, 135L, 88L, 
    130L), v26 = c(0.315039578, 0.311936937, 0.29330254, 0.344060854, 
    0.282149712, 0.278916061, 0.282376502, 0.329403606, 0.294530154, 
    0.278936017, 0.280089153, 0.314632297, 0.312738368, 0.349194167, 
    0.284834488, 0.369075369, 0.33022533, 0.341900312, 0.355015674, 
    0.315003928, 0.343949045, 0.300653595, 0.305970149, 0.297678275, 
    0.308600337, 0.37649063, 0.336743393, 0.311320755, 0.304982818, 
    0.337359793, 0.292894281, 0.324934839, 0.280210158, 0.324846356, 
    0.296557811, 0.306985294, 0.281453868, 0.298689139, 0.3246878, 
    0.325266215, 0.278978389, 0.309594461), v27 = c(0.177836412, 
    0.165540541, 0.207274827, 0.181392627, 0.161868202, 0.168539326, 
    0.162216288, 0.188626907, 0.192145863, 0.191229331, 0.182763744, 
    0.193328279, 0.15942029, 0.214888718, 0.158583526, 0.212898213, 
    0.188034188, 0.21728972, 0.229623824, 0.204241948, 0.208598726, 
    0.189542484, 0.195688226, 0.176616915, 0.228499157, 0.23253833, 
    0.210571185, 0.180102916, 0.204467354, 0.218291631, 0.185441941, 
    0.198088619, 0.187390543, 0.222124671, 0.171226831, 0.186580882, 
    0.187325256, 0.203183521, 0.195965418, 0.214908035, 0.15324165, 
    0.205736894), v28 = c(0.150923483, 0.140765766, 0.160508083, 
    0.135751902, 0.136916187, 0.124917383, 0.126835781, 0.147711512, 
    0.145862553, 0.150970525, 0.143387816, 0.166793025, 0.122807018, 
    0.162701458, 0.124711316, 0.181818182, 0.139083139, 0.164330218, 
    0.178683386, 0.140612726, 0.152866242, 0.140522876, 0.155887231, 
    0.118573798, 0.163575042, 0.186541738, 0.176470588, 0.155231561, 
    0.14604811, 0.154443486, 0.136915078, 0.151172893, 0.129597198, 
    0.172958736, 0.140335393, 0.140625, 0.138863001, 0.172284644, 
    0.136407301, 0.181994192, 0.125736739, 0.168150346), v29 = c(0.132453826, 
    0.124436937, 0.137413395, 0.125219427, 0.1081254, 0.101123596, 
    0.099465955, 0.122052705, 0.128330996, 0.117181884, 0.11589896, 
    0.13570887, 0.110602593, 0.135072909, 0.093918399, 0.149184149, 
    0.127428127, 0.151869159, 0.148119122, 0.122545169, 0.124203822, 
    0.129901961, 0.138474295, 0.104477612, 0.150927487, 0.149914821, 
    0.140664962, 0.138078902, 0.114261168, 0.144952545, 0.116117851, 
    0.117289314, 0.134851138, 0.139596137, 0.099735216, 0.115808824, 
    0.11276794, 0.154494382, 0.11623439, 0.137463698, 0.100196464, 
    0.154302671), v30 = c(0.127176781, 0.107545045, 0.122979215, 
    0.104154476, 0.079974408, 0.08988764, 0.085447263, 0.102635229, 
    0.105890603, 0.102803738, 0.101040119, 0.114480667, 0.104500381, 
    0.121258634, 0.090839107, 0.128205128, 0.097125097, 0.112149533, 
    0.132445141, 0.113118617, 0.113057325, 0.105392157, 0.109452736, 
    0.094527363, 0.122259696, 0.131175468, 0.126172208, 0.130360206, 
    0.103092784, 0.114754098, 0.086655113, 0.112076455, 0.106830123, 
    0.107989464, 0.096204766, 0.097426471, 0.094128611, 0.142322097, 
    0.097982709, 0.130687318, 0.086444008, 0.128585559), v31 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), v32 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), v33 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), v34 = c(56.79, 
    21.3, 61.69, 25.32, 26.61, 30.74, 12.27, 28.28, 14.06, 60.78, 
    47.08, 49.89, 28.02, 31.36, 18.6, 47.05, 37.49, 106, 97.55, 
    11.94, 39, 263.52, 108.16, 67.07, 53.43, 87.77, 14.13, 75.87, 
    12.6, 12.95, 10.09, 27.49, 24.97, 16.63, 10.8, 9.55, 15.57, 
    44.67, 82.29, 113.53, 12.9, 51.52)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", 
"v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8", "v9", "v10", "v11", "v12", 
"v13", "v14", "v15", "v16", "v17", "v18", "v19", "v20", "v21", 
"v22", "v23", "v24", "v25", "v26", "v27", "v28", "v29", "v30", 
"v31", "v32", "v33", "v34"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-42L))
```

I want perform cluster analysis , but my resuts is not satisfactory for me.
When i perform on full data, i get non uniform distribution of obs. in clusters.

```
mydata=read.csv("C:/Users/admin/downloads/dataset.csv", sep=";",dec=",")
dput()
str(mydata)
dist(mydata)
result <- hclust(dist(mydata), method = "complete", members = NULL)
```

for example
[image: cluster's distirbution example]

for example in the first cluster only 1 obs., but in sixth cluster 3254 obs.

Is there the way to iterate  the algorithm until in a certain number of clusters*(it is never known beforehand how many clusters to take)* there will be the maximum possible uniform distribution of observations in clusters.
Not necessarily through `hclust`, perhaps there is a better solution for such a task and then save each observation belonging to its cluster
like this ?

```
    v1    v2 vn  v34 cluster
1 1895  6.14 NA 56.79       1
2 1776  8.94 NA 21.30       1
3 1732 11.41 NA 61.69       1
4 1709  0.14 NA 25.32       2
5 1563  2.68 NA 26.61       2
6 1513  4.73 NA 30.74       2
7 1498  1.61 NA 12.27       3
8 1442  1.43 NA 28.28       3
9 1426  0.00 NA 14.06       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option with `kmeans`:

```
clusters = c(3:10)

data = list()
for(i in clusters){
  km = kmeans(na.omit(mydata),centers=10)
  clusterData = mydata
  clusterData$cluster = km$cluster
  data[[i]] = clusterData
}
```

You can iterate over some number of clusters and make a list with the results for each one. Then check the distribution for each one with `sapply(data,function(x) table(x$cluster))`

Comment: suppose i chosen 5 clusters. How can i join beloning obs. to the clusters in dataframe data like in my example